# How can I combine two separate makefiles to compile a program?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, makefile

I have two makefiles, however, I would like to ideally have one with effects of both to compile a program (test.cpp) in Ubuntu.

First (used for Basler Pylon5 Camera SDK):

```
# Makefile for Basler pylon sample program
.PHONY: all clean

# The program to build
NAME       := test

# Installation directories for pylon
PYLON_ROOT ?= /opt/pylon5

# Build tools and flags
LD         := $(CXX)
CPPFLAGS   := $(shell $(PYLON_ROOT)/bin/pylon-config --cflags)
CXXFLAGS   := #e.g., CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 for debugging
LDFLAGS    := $(shell $(PYLON_ROOT)/bin/pylon-config --libs-rpath)
LDLIBS     := $(shell $(PYLON_ROOT)/bin/pylon-config --libs)

# Rules for building
all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(NAME).o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

$(NAME).o: $(NAME).cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(NAME).o $(NAME)
```

Second (used for OpenCV):

```
# The program to build
NAME       := test

CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

$(NAME) : $(NAME).cpp
    g++ -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Is this possible?  I'm very new to makefiles and I'm just trying to capture and process some images with a camera.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: These two makefiles do *two different things*. I suppose you could run them one after the other (`make -f makefileName1; make -f makefileName2`), but there's no magic command to tell the computer "do what I would want if I knew what these things actually do".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

There is no generic solution. On the other hand, the second Makefile is a pure wrapper for these two lines:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

All you need to do, is to integrate the two lines into the first Makefile. For example, analogous to the `pylon-config` you already have there, add before `all:`

```
CXXFLAGS   += $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
LDLIBS     += $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: @macko656, do not forget to accept the answer.